# How to get a list of streets from OpenStreetMaps for a populated place in a given country?

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I am trying to extract lists of street names by names of populated places from OpenStreetMap / Overpass using e.g. the following Python code:

```
import requests
overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
  area
[name="Fulda"];
way(area)[highway][name];
out;
"""

query = overpass_query
response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': query})
data = response.json()
```

In this way I can get more or less everything I need, but the problem is how to avoid the ambiguity with the place names: there is a city in Germany called Fulda and a number or places in the US. The code above returns streets in all of them. Is there a possibility to modify the query so that it filters one certain country, e.g. Germany?

(I find BTW that the learning curve of OpenStreetMap is made unnecessarily steep, and it is difficult to find examples in the whole of the internet.)